# Linear Algebra: $\space AB=BA \space$ matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to solve a problem about $\space AB=BA. \space$
Below is the problem:

We have matrix

$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&0&2\\0&2&0\end{pmatrix}$

​
When $\space AB=BA \space$ find eigenvectors of $\space B$.

I tried to figure out what $B$ was, but I failed...
I will be grateful if someone help me find what is $B$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only know about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, which is given.

Let $v$ be in the eigenspace $E_A(\lambda)$ of $A$ relative to $\lambda$, so $Av=\lambda v$. Then $ABv=BAv=B(\lambda v)=\lambda Bv$, which proves that $v\mapsto Bv$ defines a linear map of $E_A(\lambda)$ to itself.

That's in general as much as you can say, but your $A$ is known! It's not difficult to show that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(2-X)^2(2+X)$.

Consider the eigenvalue $-2$, which has multiplicity $1$. The above considerations show that if $v\in E_A(-2)$, we have $Bv=\mu v$ for some $\mu$, because $E_A(-2)$ has dimension $1$. Hence any eigenvector of $A$ relative to $-2$ is an eigenvector for $B$ (but we can't know with respect to what eigenvalue).

The eigenvalue $2$ ha geometric multiplicity $2$, because $A-2I$ has rank $1$. So you can say nothing about the eigenvectors of $B$.

That's as much you can say, apart from computing an eigenvector for $B$ using those of $A$.

---

The same argument can be used to prove that if the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then any matrix $B$ commuting with $A$ is diagonalizable as well and that there is an invertible matrix that diagonalizes both.

If your matrix had, say, $3$ at the top left position, it would have three distinct eigenvalues and so $B$ would have three linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: $A-2I$ has rank 1, I would say

Comment: Since I'm a novice , I cannot understand what geometric multiplicity or characteristic polynomial means... I will be grateful if you explain with easier terms. So far I understood that A(Bv)=lamda(Bv) so eigenvector of A(v) is related to Bv. Also since Bv = lamda(of B)v,  v is an eigenvector of B and it is related to eigenvector of A. Is it right?

Comment: @PeterFranek oops

Comment: v↦Bv defines a linear map of EA(λ) to itself.  What does this mean? I selected your answer. I will be grateful if you would answer my question. Thank you

Comment: @Korea19800 Do you know about linear maps? If a vector space $V$ has dimension $1$, then a linear map $f\colon V\to V$ can only be of the form $f(v)=av$, for a fixed scalar $a$.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ has two [eigenspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspaces,_geometric_multiplicity,_and_the_eigenbasis_for_matrices), 2-dimensional $V_2$ and a one-dimensional $V_{-2}$. The one-dimensional space $V_{-2}$ is also an eigenspace of $B$, since $A$ and $B$ commute. (To see this, note that $Av = -2v$ implies $A(Bv) = B(Av) = -2 (Bv)$ which implies that $Bv \in V_{-2}$. But $V_{-2}$ is one-dimensional, so $Bv$ must be a multiple of $v$.)

So we can say that $v = (0, 1, -1)$ is an eigenvector of $B$. We cannot say anything about the $B$-eigenvalue.

Unfortunately, not much more can be said. $B$ could have two different eigenvectors in $V_2$ with different eigenvalues, or only one (and not be diagonalizable at all).

To summarize: $B$ has one eigenvector $(0, 1, -1)$ and at least another one in the subspace $\langle (1,0,0), (0,1,1)\rangle$.

(Thanks @egreg for the correction)

Comment: Unfortunately, $A$ has a multiple eigenvalue.

Comment: I completely missed it, thanks for the remark. Will update my answer

Comment: A has 2 eigenvalues: 2 and -2